# Transformers fine tune model warning

Tags: huggingface-transformers

```
python run_clm.py \
    --model_name_or_path ctrl \
    --train_file df_finetune_train.csv \
    --validation_file df_finetune_test.csv \
    --do_train \
    --do_eval \
    --preprocessing_num_workers 72 \
    --block_size 256 \
    --output_dir ./finetuned
```

I am trying to fine tune the ctrl model on my own dataset, where each row represents a sample.
However, I got the warning info below.

> [WARNING|tokenization_utils_base.py:3213] 2021-03-25 01:32:22,323 >>
> Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum
> sequence length for this model (934 > 256). Running this sequence
> through the model will result in indexing errors

What is the cause for this ? any solutions ?

Comment: One of your samples is longer in terms of tokens as the supported size by the model.

Comment: Did you solve this eventually?